# C++: How to find a and b from k = 2^a * b?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, cryptography

Given following in C++:

$$k = 2^a \cdot b,$$

only knowing the value of k and that b is odd. How do you find the value for a and the value for b?

I did consider the following:

1. if k is odd, a has to be zero and b is k
2. if k is even, I would go through all possible b's with a for-loop and check if k % b == 0. If that is the case, I would take log2(k/b) and if that gives me back an integer, b = k/b and a = log2(b).

My problem: how do I check if log2(k/b) gives me back an integer?

C++ code:

```
Big k(9);
int r = 4;
int n = pow(2,r);
if (k % 2 == 1)
{
    a = 0;
    b = k;
}
else
{
    for (int b = 1; b < n; b += 2)
    {
        if (k % b == 0 && LOGARITHM OF k / b IS POSSIBLE)
        {
            a = log2(b);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way: n is given as well. Everything but a and b is given.

Comment: Consider what 2<sup>a represents, and look at some examples (k == 4 or k == 6).

Comment: Can you show the complete code? What's the type of `k`?

Comment: k is of type Big

Comment: @KuroiRyū What is "Big"?

Comment: A quick note about `pow`: it operate on floating point numbers and floating point numbers are not precise. You'er going to find cases where you expect a nice, whole number, but instead get a number that's slightly over or under the expected. This discrepancy gets bigger as the numbers get larger and the space between the 
representable  numbers increases.. Even if you manage numbers that are close to the expected and convert them back into integers, the slightly lower numbers will be truncated and you'll wind up off by one.

Comment: Are k, a and b integers only? My guest is yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do the following:

```
int a = 0;
while (k % 2 == 0) {
  ++a;
  k /= 2;
}
int b = k;
// you have a, b
```

idest, divide by 2 the number `2**a*b` until it is no longer even, so you found `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `k` is `unsigned int`,

```
#include <bit>

...

int a = std::countr_zero(k);
unsigned int b = k >> a;
```

Comment: It is in C++ 20, and g++ seems doesn't have it yet.